# Producing energy with entanglement

Tags: energy, quantum-entanglement

If we entangle two electrons for example and move one of the electron to Mars for instance. Are we able to somehow transfer the kinetic force of Mars from its movement (spinning and orbitting) to Earth and use it as a source of energy?

Comment: The short answer is "no".entanglement is the term used for quantum mechanical correlation, and as always "correlation does not mean causation". The electron on mars, when/if it interacts with the Mars fields,  will become uncorrelated to the electron on earth. Any energy transfer needs an interaction

Comment: Thanks. Can i ask what do you mean that it becomes uncorrelated when it interacts with Mars field? Are you saying once entangled they remain so only on earth? Why is that? What does a planet's field to do with correlation?

Comment: @annav Might as well post as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entanglement is the term used for quantum mechanical correlation, and as always "correlation does not mean causation". In quantum mechanics most yes/no correlations come from conservation of quantum numbers. Conservation laws are strict as for example angular momentum conservation. If two electrons are set up to have spin up and spin down, the total spin being zero, if one of them interacts and we measure its spin during the interaction, then we know the spin of the other because of prior knowledge/correlation  and the conservation law .

The electron on mars, when/if it interacts with the Mars fields, will become uncorrelated to the electron on earth .  To know its spin one has to do a measurement, i.e. an interaction. Any energy transfer needs an interaction. Once the Mrs electron has interacted in Mars and we measure its spin,  we know that the spin on earth is the opposite, because of prior knowledge.

There is no energy transfer from the Mars electron back to earth, the electron scatters and gives its energy to the measuring device . In case of interacting with  the electric and magnetic and gravitational fields  of Mars, the correlation is lost. That's all.